# Compiling C code for the ARM platform to create a Windows Phone 8 compatible DLL?

Tags: c, windows-phone-8, arm

I have an old C code project from MSVC 6 that I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2013.  I want to compile the C code to an ARM compatible DLL that I can PInvoke from a Windows Phone 8 app.  When I go to the Build Configuration dialog, the only platform choice I see is Win32.  How do I set up Visual Studio to compile C code to ARM compatible DLLs?

Advanced Q: how to set things up conveniently so that the code is compiled to x86 code when I run my app on the Emulator, and to ARM code when I run it directly on the phone (Device)?

Comment: Which edition of VS2013 do you have? Do you at least see x64?

Comment: There's a video from BUILD that may help: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-049

Comment: And, did you create a C++ component using the VS templates?

Comment: @deviantfan VS2013 Ultimate.  No I only see Win32.  In my C# projects I see x86, x64, and ARM, but for the C project only Win32.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks for the video link.  re: C++.  No component.  I simply imported the old DWS project directly and VS2013 did a "one-way upgrade" to the new SLN format.  In fact, I'll probably using the option to Compile as C instead of C++, otherwise I'll get a slew of errors due to C++ name munging, etc.